# SelectInput R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, roracle

I am a beginner in R shiny. I use an Oracle database.

I have a table `T_Client(CLI_ID, CLI_NAME, CLI_INFO)`.

I display `CLI_NAME` from `T_CLIENT`in selectinput which I used reactive function `sqlOutput()`

But I can't display all columns from `T_CLIENT` in the `renderTable`, the funCtion `sqlOutput()` doesn't work well.

Any help please ? Thanks in advance.

```
library(DBI)
library(ROracle)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  uiOutput("ui_assetClass"),
  tableOutput("table2"))

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output, session= open()) {
    
    drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
    host <- "host"
    port <- xxxx
    svc <- "svc"
    connect.string <- paste(
      "(DESCRIPTION=", "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
      "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=", svc, ")))", sep = "")
    DB <- dbConnect(drv, username = "username", password = "password", dbname = connect.string)
    
    
    sqlOutput<- reactive({
      
   sqlInput<- dbGetQuery(DB,"select CLI_NAME from T_CLIENT")
      
      sqlInput
    })
    
    output$ui_assetClass <- renderUI({
      selectInput(" Clients", "choose client", choices = sqlOutput())
    })
    
    
    dabaBaseInput2 <- reactive({
      x <- dbGetQuery(DB, sprintf("SELECT CLI_ID, CLI_NAME, CLI_INFO FROM T_CLIENT where CL_NOM = '%s' ",sqlOutput()))
      x
    })
    
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
      dabaBaseInput2()
    })
    
  })
```

Comment: You have only one variable in `sqlInput<- dbGetQuery(DB,"select CLI_NAME from T_CLIENT")`

Comment: Yes I have only one variable that I choose from selectInput and I should display it from renderTable, what is wrong ? @YBS

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your statement "I Can't display all columns from T_CLIENT in the `renderTable`, the function `sqlOutput()` don't work well. ".  I think `dabaBaseInput2` looks fine to me.